# Sample Asp.net Core MVC Grid with Kendo UI like functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a grid bind with SQL Server data.

This grid should have the following functionalities:

1. Sorting
2. Filtering based on Columns
3. Pagination

Can anyone of us please share some sample opensource grid having such functionalities.

Comment: Forgot to add Not want to use Jquery, Angular, React or any JS framework Grid. Only need to add C# and Asp.net Core MVC for Grid binding.

Comment: Are you asking if there are any vanilla js datagrids that support sorting, filtering and paging? Or are you looking to not use any JS at all?

Comment: @jon No JS grid at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for "Kendo UI like functionality" without any JS. Then your only real option is a Blazor:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor

If you don't want to use JS or Blazor then "Kendo UI like functionality" won't be possible.

If it's simply basic paging, sorting and filtering, and you just wish to do that using standard HTTP requests and do all the paging, sorting and filtering server side then you should be able to follow Microsoft's guidance on that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0